# populating dropdown from ajax database call

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

In my current code, the `record` is not coming back as a list I can iterate through. Instead, it goes through `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[ProjectName.BodyStyle]` for the `$.each` function.

What I need is a list I can go through and pull `ID` and `BodyStyle1` from to fill a drop down. Here is my code:

Server-Side Controller:

```
Function Index(ByVal KovID As String) As List(Of BodyStyle)
            Dim db As New Database1Entities
            Dim record As New List(Of BodyStyle)
            record = (From b In db.BodyStyles Where b.KovID = KovID Select b).ToList
            Return record
        End Function
```

Jquery:

```
function ajaxSuccess(record) {
        var drop2 = $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value');
        drop2.get(0).options.length = 0;
        drop2.get(0).options[0] = new Option("Please Select One", "-1");
        $.each(record, function (index, item) {
            alert(index);
            alert(item);
            drop2.get(0).options[drop2.get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
        });
    }

    function ajaxError() {
        $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length = 0;
        $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[0] = new Option("Error!", "-1");
        alert("Failed to load styles");
    }

    $('#Vehicle_KovId_value').change(function () {
        var kovID = $(this).val();
        var drop2 = $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value');
        if (kovID != null && kovID != '') {
            drop2.get(0).options.length = 0;
            drop2.get(0).options[0] = new Option('Please Select One', '-1');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Ajax/Index',
                async: false,
                data: { KovID: kovID },
                contentType: "application/object; charset=utf-8",
                success: ajaxSuccess,
                error: ajaxError
            });
        }
    });
```

What I need to do is return `record` as something I can go through and pull information from. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using WebAPI methods in the server-side code then I would expect it to be serializing to JSON for you, but for reasons unknown here that doesn't seem to be happening.  Somehow the `List(Of BodyStyle)` is just being converted into a string, which is resulting in that output.

I'm sure there are other things to do in order to make this more idiomatic WebAPI functionality, but in a pinch you can always manually return a JSON serialized string using [the `JavaScriptSerializer` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292287.aspx).

You'd change the method signature to return a string:

```
Function Index(ByVal KovID As String) As String
```

And then return a serialized string of the object:

```
Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(record)
```

Comment: That did help, though now I have a very long string that I'm unsure how to handle. But that one I can get help from here in the office. Thank you very much, David.

Comment: @Kendra: If the long string is an the contents of the list, then chances are it's an array of records in your JavaScript code.  (Something you can iterate over, for example.)  It *should* just be a JavaScript representation of the same value of `record` in the server-side code.  (Which I think should be called `records` (plural), since it's a list.)

Comment: It is. I just need to figure out how to tweak the code to iterate through it correctly. Because right now, when the `$.each` function iterates through the code, it's going character by character, which doesn't quite work for filling the dropdown with the appropriate information.

Comment: @Kendra: Interesting.  If it's coming back as a string then it may be wrapped in quotes in the JavaScript side.  Which leads me to believe that this is still *trying* to be a WebAPI method, but something is getting in its way.  I definitely recommend looking into why the original method wasn't working, because all this ended up being is a workaround, not a solution.  Continuing down this path may just lead to more workarounds.

Comment: I will definitely look into this tomorrow, then, as my work day is done and all of the project is on my work computer. Thank you for your help, David. If you think of something, let me know, otherwise I'll research and look into it tomorrow.